# Creating a Spark dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

Having trouble creating two dataframes and doing a `union` on them.

This works:

```
a = [{'letter':'a'}]
sqlContext.createDataFrame(a).collect()
b = [{'letter':'b'}]
sqlContext.createDataFrame(b).collect()
```

But if I run `rdd = sc.union([a,b])`, I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_jrdd_deserializer'`

So I figured I need to do `sc.parallelize()`. I'm not sure 100% what this does even after reading documentation. Could someone explain this function at a high level?

So I did:

```
a = sc.parallelize(['a'])
sqlContext.createDataFrame(a).collect()
```

but I still get an error, this time: `TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <type 'str'>`

I'm just trying to understand all the syntax and the types, and functions needed to simply create 2 dataframes and union them.

Answer (score 3):

In your first approach you did not create RDDs/DataFrames so `sc.union([a, b])` is trying to union two lists, not RDDs nor DataFrames, hence you get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_jrdd_deserializer'`.

Here's a snippet if you want to operate on DataFrames

```
a = [{'letter':'a'}]
b = [{'letter':'b'}]

a_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(a)
b_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(b)

a_df.unionAll(b_df).collect()
```

with the output

```
[Row(letter=u'a'), Row(letter=u'b')]
```

Alternatively, RDD operations would be

```
r = sc.union([
        sc.parallelize([e['letter'] for e in a]),
        sc.parallelize([e['letter'] for e in b]),
    ])

r.collect()
```

with the output

```
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: Thanks, so it looks like I was doing 3 things incorrectly: not assigning the `createDataFrame` to a variable, using the `collect()` method, and the `union` syntax being different. Or is the `sc.union` still a viable method?

Comment: `sc.union` is still a good method if you work with RDDs. You could simply pass this `sc.union([sc.parallelize(a), sc.parallelize(b)]).collect()` (note the `sc.parallelize(...)`) for a `[{'letter': 'a'}, {'letter': 'b'}]` output.